# UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL

Tags: undefined-behavior, cs50

I was working on Problem Set 4 in CS50, this code compiled well; however, once I ran it, it totally crushed and gave me this error message:

```
UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer:DEADLYSIGNAL
==13838==ERROR: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x7fae6282690a (pc 0x0000004292c7 bp 0x7fff28e4e760 sp 0x7fff28e49530 T13838)
==13838==The signal is caused by a READ memory access.
    #0 0x4292c6  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x4292c6)
    #1 0x4232b1  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x4232b1)
    #2 0x7fae61719b96  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21b96)
    #3 0x402dd9  (/home/ubuntu/pset4/filter/filter+0x402dd9)

UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer can not provide additional info.
==13838==ABORTING
```

During my work on the previous filters, no error appeared and everything worked well, just as I implemented this new code, it gave me this fault. I tried replacing 0 by 1 so that I automatically access the first pixel and so on; however It did not work and I suppose that it is not correct; therefore, I put it back to 0. I would be grateful for any help. Thank you very much.

```
#include "helpers.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Blur image
void blur(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    int sumred;
    int sumgreen;
    int sumblue;
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int n = 0; n < width / 2; n++)
        {
            if (i == 0 && n == 0)
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtRed)/4);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen)/4);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue)/4);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1) && n == (width -1))
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtRed)/4);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen)/4);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue)/4);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && n == (width - 1))
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtRed)/4);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen)/4);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue)/4);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1) && n == 0)
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtRed)/4);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen)/4);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue)/4);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i == 0 && n != 0 && n != (width -1))
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed)/6);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen)/6);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue)/6);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i != 0 && i != (height - 1) && n == 0)
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed)/6);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n].rgbtGreen)/6);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n].rgbtBlue)/6);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i == (height - 1) && n != 0 && n != (width - 1))
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtRed)/6);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen)/6);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue)/6);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else if (i != 0 && i != (height - 1) && n == (width - 1))
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed)/6);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n].rgbtGreen)/6);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n].rgbtBlue)/6);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
            else
            {
                sumred = ((image[i][n].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n].rgbtRed + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtRed + image[i][n + 1].rgbtRed)/9);
                sumgreen = ((image[i][n].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n].rgbtGreen + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtGreen + image[i][n + 1].rgbtGreen)/9);
                sumblue = ((image[i][n].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n - 1].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n].rgbtBlue + image[i + 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i - 1][n + 1].rgbtBlue + image[i][n + 1].rgbtBlue)/9);
                image[i][n].rgbtRed = sumred;
                image[i][n].rgbtGreen = sumgreen;
                image[i][n].rgbtBlue = sumblue;
            }
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I tried to round the values now but the error remains the same.

Comment: Yeah, I finally found the answer, I was assigning 'i' a value  - 1 :)